# How to get the parameter from AWS Systems Parameter store using AWS SDK in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm going to get the password parameter from AWS SSM using AWS SDK in the browser.

I got the way how to get the parameter in Node.js, but didn't get the correct answer to get the parameter in the browser.

Is there way to get the parameter from AWS SSM in the browser?